# Jenkins' /etc/default/jenkins not update safe?

Tags: jenkins, apt

I installed Jenkins using `apt-get install jenkins`. Then I made some changes in `/etc/default/jenkins` (which is, as far as I know, the only way to change the Jenkins system user etc.). Now I found out that this file becomes reverted with every update (using `apt-get update`).

In addition I changed the owner of some files of the jenkins installation (e.g. `/var/lib/jenkins`, `/var/log/jenkins` and some others) because I changed the user under which jenkins should run. Also these permission changes are reverted after every update.

There are two solutions I could think about, both not really "nice" and clean:

1. Install and run the jenkins.war manually without any package management
2. Write a DPKG-Post-Install-Trigger that fixes the problems after every update

Does anyone have a cleaner solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Two answers occur to me

1) Download the source package that apt-get uses and modify the users, permissions etc to suit your local use.  Rebuild the package and either install it from cli with dpkg -i or make your own repository for local use.

or

2) Use a tool like puppet to manage the package install and then apply the changes required locally afterwards.  The puppet "package/file/service" pattern explained in various places including here https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet_core_types_cheatsheet.pdf shows how to do the puppet manifests for this

Comment: Ok, but if I'm right 1) does not allow for further updates without manual intervention 2) is quite the same like my Post-Install-Trigger. But maybe there is just no better solution.. :(

Comment: 1) yes it's just to make a package that could be applied to multiple hosts.  It could pull in changes from upstream and alter the package and build a new one fairly automatically but it wouldn't be as easy as ``apt-get upgrade`` 2) yes, it's like your post-install trigger.  I don't have a working jenkins right here now at work to test but ISTR now, thinking about it, that at least on Ubunutu 12.04 LTS ``/etc/default/jenkins`` file isn't clobbered by a package upgrade!  I'm pretty sure that this generally isn't the case for files in ``/etc/default``